# How can i use html.actionlink or ajax.action in option tag asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My Actionlink is not working Please Help

```
  <div data-role="select">
        <select id="js-data-example-ajax" name="js-data-example-ajax">
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
   <option value=" 3620194">
   @Html.ActionLink(@item.ProductName, "GetByID", new { Area = "Common", ID = item.ProductID })
   </option>
  }
</select>
</div>
```

OR

```
   <div data-role="select">
   <select id="js-data-example-ajax" name="js-data-example-ajax">
 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
   <option value=" 3620194">
   @Ajax.ActionLink(@item.ProductName, "GetByID", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "js-data-example-ajax", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith })
   </option>
  }
</select>
</div>
```

In Home Controller action link is not going on GetByID method

```
    public ViewResult GetByID(string ID)
    {
       return View();
    }
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: when i select (click) any value from dropdownlist it doesn't go to the GetByID ViewResult Method in Controller.I've tried both html.action & ajax.action,but both are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links inside `option` elements are not rendered as a link. Instead you need to handle the click yourself, for example with jQuery. You could do something like this:

#### HTML

```
<div data-role="select">
    <select id="js-data-example-ajax" name="js-data-example-ajax">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <option value="3620194" data-url="@Url.Action("GetByID", new { Area = "Common", ID = item.ProductID })">
                @item.ProductName
            </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#js-data-example-ajax').on('change', function() {
            var url = $('#js-data-example-ajax').find(":selected").data('url');
            document.location = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its Working Thanks Alot!

Comment: i'm not eligible for upvote i'm newbie my reputation only 9